# Stripe php : How to managed custom amount based plans?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

How to managed custom amount based plans code in stripe payment?

Plan id : basic-{interval}-{amount}

1) Check plan exits or not ?

if : exits then assign to subscriber

not - Create a new plan.

```
if(!empty($recurring_duration)){
                                try {
                                    $plan = \Stripe\Plan::retrieve($planname);
                                } catch (Error\InvalidRequest $exception) {
                                    $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
                                        "name" => "Basic Plan",
                                        "id" => $planname,    
                                        "interval" => "$recurring_duration",
                                        "currency" => strtolower($currency),
                                        "amount" => $amount,
                                    ));
                                }

                                $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
                                        "name" => "Basic Plan",
                                        "id" => $planname,    
                                        "interval" => "$recurring_duration",
                                        "currency" => strtolower($currency),
                                        "amount" => $amount,
                                ));
                            } 

$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                                'email'     => $email,
                                'source'    => $token
                            ));

                            if(!empty($recurring_duration)){

                                $charge = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
                                    "customer" => $customer->id,
                                    "items" => array(
                                      array(
                                        "plan" => $planname,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                ));

                            }else{

                                $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                                                'customer'    => $customer->id,
                                                'amount'      => $amount,
                                                'currency'    => strtolower($currency),
                                                'description' => '',
                                        )
                                ); 

                            }

                            $val = BSP_add_form_data($charge);
```

Comment: Any code you can share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Need to get all plans & check with your values.

```
<?php
$recurring_duration  = $_POST['recurring_duration'];
$planname = "plan value";
$last_customer = NULL;
while (true) {
    $plan_list = \Stripe\Plan::all(array("limit" => 100, "starting_after" => $last_plan));
    foreach ($plan_list->autoPagingIterator() as $plan) {
        if ($plan->id == $planname) {
            $planlookfor = $plan;
            break 2;
        }
    }
    if (!$plan->has_more) {
        break;
    }
    $last_plan = end($plan_list->data);
}

if(!empty($recurring_duration)){
    if(isset($planlookfor) && $planlookfor->id==$planname){

    }else{
        $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
            "name" => 'Basic Plan'.' '.$recurring_duration_text.' '.$amount/100,
            "id" => $planname,    
            "interval" => "$recurring_duration",
            "currency" => strtolower($currency),
            "amount" => $amount,
        ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are doing too much plan creation. Your code is there but once you have the plan then you dont need to recreate it.
Here are simple steps.

1. Create Customer
2. Check if plan can be retrieved. Store it in $plan if it can be.
3. If not create a new plan and store it in $plan
4. Check if recurring duration is not empty then assign plan to customer
5. Otherwise charge amount to customer

Now from your code after you have done exception check you have created plan then you dont need to create it again after it.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                            'email'     => $email,
                            'source'    => $token
                        ));
if(!empty($recurring_duration)){
                            try {
                                $plan = \Stripe\Plan::retrieve($planname);
                                //got plan
                            } catch (Error\InvalidRequest $exception) {
                                //create new plan
                                $plan = \Stripe\Plan::create(array(
                                    "name" => "Basic Plan",
                                    "id" => $planname,    
                                    "interval" => "$recurring_duration",
                                    "currency" => strtolower($currency),
                                    "amount" => $amount,
                                ));
                            }
                            $charge = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
                                "customer" => $customer->id,
                                "items" => array(
                                  array(
                                    "plan" => $planname,
                                  ),
                                ),
                            ));
                    }else{
                          $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                                            'customer'    => $customer->id,
                                            'amount'      => $amount,
                                            'currency'    => strtolower($currency),
                                            'description' => '',
                                    )
                            );   
                    }
$val = BSP_add_form_data($charge);
```

I have created customer first as that would always be needed.

Comment: yes but when check retrieve plans that time issue. Return a message.